# Does this sequence of integer products have a name?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, catalan-numbers

Suppose that I have a product of, say, $n=4$ integers starting with one and ending with four $1234=4!=24$. Now I construct all products of four positive integers $1,2,3$ and $4$ with repetition such that  the difference between the integer on the $k$-th and $(k-1)$-st position is less or equal to one for $k=2,\dots,n$.

The rule looks contrived so here is the list of all possibilities for $n=4$ to get an idea:
$$
1234\\
1233\\
1232\\
1231\\
1223\\
1222\\
1221\\
1212\\
1211\\
1123\\
1122\\
1121\\
1112\\
1111
$$

My questions: Does such a sequence of products have a name (for arbitrary $n$) and is there a formula for the sum of the products?

The list has 14 products which is one of the Catalan numbers (not a coincidence).

Answer (score 0):

well this is the best i could find online.

https://books.google.com/books?id=5NvrH4w8WGsC&pg=PA428&lpg=PA428&dq=1234+1233+1232+1231+1223+1222+1221+1212+1211+1123+1122+1121+1112+1111&source=bl&ots=WMylvj0faU&sig=z9HjmCWEKl80qCZxcXx2-GaxluY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DuQTVcu4McnlUsuJgcAC&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=1234%201233%201232%201231%201223%201222%201221%201212%201211%201123%201122%201121%201112%201111&f=false

maybe you have to give it a name yourself :D